# How to match string behind character in QT using RegExp?

Tags: regex, qt, qregexp, qregularexpression

How to match every String behind ":"?
For example: want to match "3.23423" in "roll:3.23423" or "true" in "smth:true".

Comment: use  a lookbehind `(?<=:)\S+` or `(?<=:).*`

Comment: (?<=:)\S+ or (?<=:).*       doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
QRegExp rx("[a-z]+\:.+");
QString ss = "roll:3.23423";

int poss = 0;
while ((poss = rx.indexIn(ss, poss)) != -1) {
    qDebug( )<< rx.cap(0).split(":").last();
    poss += rx.matchedLength();
}
```

Output:

```
"3.23423"
```

But one man told me that `split()` can be slow, so you can use also:

```
QRegExp rx("[a-z]+\:.+");
QString ss = "roll:3.23423";

int poss = 0;
while ((poss = rx.indexIn(ss, poss)) != -1) {

    QString g = rx.cap(0);
    int p = rx.cap(0).indexOf(":");
    qDebug( )<< g.mid(p+1);
    poss += rx.matchedLength();
}
```

It should be faster.

Update (before). Use this loop:

```
while ((poss = rx.indexIn(ss, poss)) != -1) {

    QString g = rx.cap(0);
    int p = rx.cap(0).lastIndexOf(":");
    qDebug( )<< g.mid(0,p);
    poss += rx.matchedLength();
}
```

Comment: thnx! how can i get string before ":"?